Simplify a boolean expression with 4 variables to 3 variables
I'm doing some simplifications for a circuit and I ended up getting the following expression:
A.C'.D' + A.B'.C' + B.C.D' + B'.C.D + A'.B'.D'
which translates to the truth table where 0, 2, 3, 6, 8, 9, 11, 12 and 14 are true, and the rest is false.
Somehow, I have to find a way to make it fit in 3 variables, and I'm thinking that this is impossible. My professor has the following expressions as alternatives:
a) A' + B.C + A.C
b) A' + B'.C + A.C
c) A' + B.C + A'.C'
d) A'.(B+C).(A'+C')
aand there is no D variable, which is something I haven't managed to replicate in 4 hours trying. It's supposedly doable with only the Karnaugh map, but I'm not sure.
I only need to know if it is possible and what should be the method. Thanks in advance.
Karnaugh map, simplification techniques and online calculators, doing it in POS and SOP forms, changing the truth table to see if it is not wrong instead. but it seems fine.
including the truth table:
A B C D | Y |
0 0 0 0 | 1 | 
0 0 0 1 | 0 | 
0 0 1 0 | 1 | 
0 0 1 1 | 1 | 
0 1 0 0 | 0 | 
0 1 0 1 | 0 | 
0 1 1 0 | 1 | 
0 1 1 1 | 0 | 
1 0 0 0 | 1 | 
1 0 0 1 | 1 | 
1 0 1 0 | 0 |
1 0 1 1 | 1 |
1 1 0 0 | 1 |
1 1 0 1 | 0 |
1 1 1 0 | 1 |
1 1 1 1 | 0 |


You can tell by looking at the truth table that D cannot be eliminated - the two last lines, for example, are the same for A, B, and C, so D must be controlling the different results.

None of these formulas are equivalent to the original.

Option A differs from the original when A=1, B=1, C=0, D=0 (1 vs 0)
Option B differs from the original when A=1, B=0, C=0, D=0 (1 vs 0)
Option C differs from the original when A=1, B=1, C=0, D=0 (1 vs 0)
Option D differs from the original when A=0, B=1, C=0, D=0 (0 vs 1)

You should make sure that there are no typos in the formulas, which can happen more often than you think.
If there are no typos, then your professor is just wrong.

the truth table is the following:
A  B  C  D  Y  |
0  0  0  0   1   |
0  0  0  1   0   |
0  0  1  0   1   |
0  0  1  1   1   |
0  1  0  0   0   |
0  1  0  1   0   |
0  1  1  0   1   |
0  1  1  1   0   |
1  0  0  0   1   |
1  0  0  1   1   |
1  0  1  0   0   |
1  0  1  1   1   |
1  1  0  0   1   |
1  1  0  1   0   |
1  1  1  0   1   |
1  1  1  1   0   |
I don't really know where I got it wrong, but if it is not me, it's indeed the professor. I don't see a way to remove the D variable completely

Prof is wrong, D cannot be eliminated:
    Kmap
    ----
AB\CD 00 01 11 10
00    1  0  1  1
01    0  0  0  1
11    1  0  0  1
10    1  1  1  0

Result:
A'.B'.D' + B'.C.D + B.C.D' + A.B'.C'

